# How to use predefined array as parameter factory in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a master job which should trigger 15 builds for each predefined market. I don't want to enter 15 separate triggers/builds with a unique parameter.

It looks like parameter factories could do the job, but they don't provide a way to pass an array of parameters to iterate over. I tried doing this:

```
MARKET=${(en_us,de_de)[$COUNT]}
```

but it didn't work. Any way to accomplish this?
Also, I'd be great if we could use a environmental variable like $MARKETS instead of harcoding them.